# Compare Integer with primitive

Tags: java, integer, equals, long-integer

I do not have a `java` compiler and I would like to check how treats `java` the comparison of `Integer` Objects with primitives. Can someone confirm that the results of the following comparisons are correct:

```
Integer a = 500;
long b = 500;
a == b  //-> false
a.equals(b)  //-> true
```

Is it generally true that in the first type of comparison java does `Boxing` and in the second `Unboxing` and compares primitive values?

Comment: It's very easy to get a JDK, an Eclipse installation and test this. But then, there's [**this**](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php)!

Comment: Ok, thanks, really helpful. Unfortunately I have no possibility to test it with a real JDK in the next hours because of installation priviledges.

Comment: You can use that website _(Compile and Execute Java online)_ which I linked in my previous comment. It runs right on your browser (well, the Java program runs on their servers). There's no need to install anything, even JRE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See my results

```
    Integer a = 500;
    long b = 500;
    System.out.println(a == b);
    System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

output

```
true
false
```

this is because the first comparison uses unboxing

```
b == a.intValue()
```

which produces true, because in Java 500L == 500 is true.

The second comparison uses boxing

```
a.equals(Long.valueOf(b))
```

this produces false because a and b are instances of different classes. See Integer.equals impl:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```